# Dos command and its output

Tags: batch-file

All,

Please guide me, how to print the o/p of below command in dos window? Being new to dos command, I do not know what below string mean?

set ts = %date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%-%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the cmd prompt.

`echo` is the command that will display a value to the screen (ex: `echo %date%`)

`set ts` is setting a variable (`ts`) which can later be called like this: `%ts%`

`%date%` is a variable that will return the system date.  `%date:~4,2%` will give the month (numeric) and `%date:~7,2%` gives the day of the month (numeric).

`%time%` is also a variable, but this on returns the time (24 hour).  `%time:~0,2%` gives the hours (24 hour style so 1pm=13).  `%time:~3,2%` gives the minutes.

Comment: Thanks @David  if you could please give me some link where I can learn this? will be helpful... cmd file has following command %consoleDir%abc.exe createfile -o %File% -p 10000 -m 8 -d 1/1/2000 -n 15000 -s %jobDir%files.txt

Comment: not sure what is the o/p of this... only I can think is that it is calling some exe file

Comment: Separate question, but I'll try.  `%consoleDir%abc.exe` is calling an executable and passing everything else as parameters.  To know exactly what it is doing, you should give the filename that is being called, but we can guess.  `-o %File%` is probably opening some variable named File.  `-d 1/1/2000` is likely setting a date. `-s %jobDir%files.txt` is likely saying "save output to `[job directory]\files.txt`.  As for `-p -m -n` I'm not sure what they do.

Comment: Thanks David, if there is any tutorial you know for DOS? let me know.. might help... :)  Thx once again

Comment: Reading around here on stackoverflow in the batch and cmd areas really helps out.

Answer (score 1):

That is setting an environment variable named `ts`.  To display the value, add this line after it:

```
echo %ts%
```

Comment: Thanks Nate, would you mind giving me some tips? I have a cmd file with following command.. if you could please give me some link where I can learn this? will be helpful... command is                                                                  %consoleDir%abc.exe createfile -o %File% -p 10000 -m 8 -d 1/1/2000 -n 15000 -s %jobDir%files.txt

Comment: Oh no it isn't! The spaces **ARE** significant. As posted, the code would set an environment variable named `"ts "` to the value of `" 0326-1004"` Confusingly, `set /A ts = %date...` will set `"ts"` not `"ts "` **BUT** it sets `ts` to the `/A` ARITHMETIC result of the expression " 0326-1004" which is, of course **-790** not -678! This is because "0326" is evaluated as OCTAL (base 8) as it has a leading "0". 0326 octal = 214 decimal; 214-1024=**-790**. Best to leave spaces out completely IMHO - and beware editors like `NOTEPAD` that leave stray spaces at the end of lines. SET **INCLUDES** them!

Comment: @Peter, could you pls suggest here on the parameters passed? I need to know what is                                                                  -p 1000, -m 8 and -8 1/1/200 means? from below command?                                                                %consoleDir%abc.exe createfile -o %File% -p 10000 -m 8 -d 1/1/2000 -n 15000 -s %jobDir%files.txt

Comment: Not the faintest idea. depends on what `abc.exe` is. I'd guess `-d 1/1/2000` is a date-specification but as for the others - no.

Answer (score 0):

This is setting a variable using some substring operations.

This `%date:~4,2%` means:

- get the date from the machine;
- remove the first 4 characters of it;
- from the result, get the first 2 characters;

The rest is repeating this process and concatenating the result in a date and time formatted string.